# Could [possible] & [impossible] tags be removed? possibly?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I don't think these tags:

- [possible](/questions/tagged/possible) with 7 questions (2 asked this year)
- [impossible](/questions/tagged/impossible) with 16 questions (3 asked this year)

provide useful meta data for the question and they really *don't* increase the search visibility of a given topic.  The posts tagged are quite varied.

Comment: Note -- no questions would be orphaned without tags if these two were removed.

Comment: You have enough rep to retag those questions yourself, and 23 questions is a reasonable amount for you to do manually.

Comment: @Michael, Sure thing!  I just didn't want to push them all to the top.  Is that ok?

Comment: I think so, yes. I see, at first glance, no reasonable uses of those tags, and it's no big deal to bump them temporarily, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So they're all gone now.  I retagged them by hand at Michael Petrotta's suggestion.